# Recreate Enterprise Manager 11g (RAC)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-enterprise-manager

Due to a supposed bad installation of the repository of Enterprise manager, I want to recreate it using:

```
emca -config dbcontrol db -repos recreate -cluster
```

I have seen in a successful simulation (Simple Environment, No RAC), which during the task is reported:

```
WARNING : While repository is dropped the database will be put in quiesce mode.
```

I would like to know the risks that I assume by executing this task in the productive environment.

Is the database affected? Does the TNS configuration change?

Answer (score 0):

In quiesce mode all running sessions can continue to complete their current task and no new connections can be made. Quiescing is much less impactful, as your users might only notice the database pauses then resumes.

To configure Oracle Enterprise Manager to RAC-[Enterprise Manager Configuration Assistant (EMCA)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/emca.htm)

Comment: Thanks.
I see, on example of recreate:

    Database unique name: orcl   --example
    Service name: orcl           --example

Must I run the same sentence, on two instances of RAC, with the same service name??? (in my case SID= orcl1  and   orcl2) 

Thanks again